# Recursion and Reverse Recursion looping through hasNext() method

Tags: java, list, collections

Hi everyone I'm new to java so Id really appreciate any help on this.
 Ok so Here is The Problem that I have encountered:
I have a list class and a listNode class, The list Class is represented by a name, a firstNode and a lastNode. firstNode and lastNode are from type listNode, a listNode is represented by an Object (for ex. data or Object o) and a nextNode which points to the next Node in the list which is also from type listNode.

List class:

```
public class List {

private ListNode firstNode;
private ListNode lastNode;
private String name;

public List() {
    this("list");
}

public List(String listName) {
    name = listName;
    firstNode = lastNode = null;
}

public void insertAtFront(Object insertItem) {
    if (isEmpty())
        firstNode = lastNode = new ListNode(insertItem);
    else
        firstNode = new ListNode(insertItem, firstNode);
}

public void insertAtBack(Object insertItem) {
    if (isEmpty())
        firstNode = lastNode = new ListNode(insertItem);
    else
        lastNode = lastNode.nextNode = new ListNode(insertItem);
}

public Object removeFromFront() throws EmptyListException {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new EmptyListException(name);
    Object removedItem = firstNode.data;

    if (firstNode == lastNode)
        firstNode = lastNode = null;
    else
        firstNode = firstNode.nextNode;
    return removedItem;
}

public Object removeFromBack() throws EmptyListException {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new EmptyListException(name);

    Object removedItem = lastNode.data;
    if (firstNode == lastNode)
        firstNode = lastNode = null;
    else {
        ListNode current = firstNode;

        while (current.nextNode != lastNode)
            current = current.nextNode;

        lastNode = current;
        current.nextNode = null;
    }
    return removedItem;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return firstNode == null;
}

public void print() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        System.out.printf("Empty %s\n", name);
        return;
    }
    System.out.printf("The %s is : ", name);
    ListNode current = firstNode;

    while (current != null) {
        System.out.printf("%s", current.data);
        current = current.nextNode;
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String stk = "(";
    if(isEmpty())return "Empty List";
    ListNode checkNode = firstNode;
        while (checkNode != null) {
        stk += checkNode.data.toString()+ " , ";
        checkNode = checkNode.nextNode;
    }
    return stk+")";
}
public ListNode removeAt (int k){
    if(k<=0 || k>getLength())
        try{
            throw new IllegalValues();
        }catch(IllegalValues iv){
            iv.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    ListNode newNode = firstNode;
    if (k==1) {
        ListNode removedNode = firstNode;
        firstNode = firstNode.nextNode;
        return removedNode;
    }
    ListNode someNode = firstNode;
    for (int i = 1; i < k - 1; i++) {
        someNode = someNode.nextNode;
    }
    ListNode removedNode = someNode.nextNode;
    someNode.nextNode = someNode.nextNode.nextNode;
    return removedNode;
}
public int getLength(){
    ListNode checkNode = firstNode;
    int count =0;
    while (checkNode != null) {
    count++;
    checkNode = checkNode.nextNode;
}
    return count;
}
public  void show(){
    if (firstNode==null)
      return;
    else
        System.out.print(firstNode + " ,");
      firstNode.show();
    }
public  void showRev(){
    if (lastNode==null)
      return;
    else
        System.out.println(lastNode + ",");
      lastNode.showRev();
    }
    }
```

ListNode Class

```
public class ListNode {

Object data;
ListNode nextNode;

public ListNode(Object o) {
    this(o, null);
}

public ListNode(Object o, ListNode node) {
    data = o;
    nextNode = node;
}

public Object getObject() {
    return data;
}

public ListNode getNext(){
    return nextNode;
}

public ListNode show() {
if(this.nextNode == null)return this;
ListNode displayMe = nextNode.show();
System.out.print(displayMe + " , ");
return displayMe;

}

public ListNode showRev() {
    if(this.firstNode == null)return this;
    ListNode displayMe = lastNode.show();
    System.out.print(displayMe + " , ");
    return displayMe;

}

}
```

I have a recursive method called show which displays all the objects in the list from the beginning to the end now I'm trying to make something similar (the method name is showRev() ) which displays the objects from the end to the beginning ( a recursive method) and I dont think it is possible to make a has previous method so im kinda stuck on this method.
Id really appreciate any Ideas
Thanks guys

Comment: Just an fyi: `show` isn't [recursive](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~calvin/cs110/RECURSION.html)

Comment: the show in the class list isn't recursive but it calls the show method in ListNode which is recursive

Comment: Nope, that just calls a method created from the same class but on a different instance. If you called `this.show`, it would've been recursive, calling `anotherNode.show` is not.

Comment: thats what I meant the showrev in listnode is recursive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `showRev` method is allowed to take an argument, then we can store every `ListNode` in a `java.util.List`:

```
public java.util.List<ListNode> showRev(java.util.List<ListNode> nodes) {
    if (this.nextNode == null) {
        Collections.reverse(nodes);

        System.out.println(nodes.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));

        return nodes;
    }

    nodes.add(lastNode.show());

    return showRev(nodes);
}
```

Note that the recursion here does nothing special but add `ListNode`s to the `java.util.List`.

To call this method, simply pass it a `new ArrayList<>()`.

Also, I would refrain from using `List` as the name for a class, as `java.util.List` can easily be confused with it.